# Timezone for member profile

Tags: php, datetime

I have this application where there is a registration page for members. When users register, i save very little information in database. Like username,password, firstname, lastname, emailid, country. After their registration is done, they can login and see their profile page. Here i need to give the time when they were registered. Currently it shows the member a different version of their registration time.

So then i modified and instead of date(), i use gmdate() for saving the time.

And now it is showing the gmt version of time.

**Question 1-** If the member sees his profile, he should see time as per his timezone.

**Question 2-** How will i get the localtime zone when there is a timezone change like daylight saving.

I understand i should take the time through javascript but i cannot rely on that to be correct. Any suggestions ?

I have seen the link [Best way to convert to a member's timezone with offsets stored in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465844/best-way-to-convert-to-a-members-timezone-with-offsets-stored-in-database) but this is  different.

Comment: You might want to use a timestamp to store the registration dates. It's timezone-independent, can be formatted more easily than pre-formatted dates, and it's not going to go out of range since the registration dates are current.

Comment: *"but this is different."* - Probably, however, whenever you refer to an existing Q&A make clear *what* is different. Also Stackoverflow works best with one question at a time. Not two as in your question.